# Type mismatch when returning an array from a function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a function, for use in subs, that creates an array of actual days in a month. I am unable to run the function by using either the Immediate window directly or with a sub. The function's code is the following (`Debug.Print` instances are removed, as they never even trigger):

```
Function GenererDager(ByVal month As Integer, ByVal year As Integer) As Integer

    Dim dateFormat As String, daysArr() As Integer, actualDays As Integer

    actualDays = 1

    ' Find the number of actual days in given month
    For dayCheck = 1 To 31

        dateFormat = month & "/" & dayCheck & "/" & year ' mm/dd/yyyy format

        If IsDate(dateFormat) Then

            actualDays = actualDays + 1

        Else

            Exit For

        End If

    Next dayCheck

    ' Redimension the array with the actual number of days in the month
    ReDim daysArr(actualDays)

    ' Populate the array with the correct number of days
    For daysToArray = 1 To actualDays

        daysArr(daysToArray) = daysToArray

    Next daysToArray

    GenererDager = daysArr

End Function
```

Running the function using the Immediate window with `GenererDager(2, 2017)` produces the following error message: `Compile error: Expected: =`

Running the function using the Immediate window with `?GenererDager(2, 2017)` produces the following error message: `Compiler error: Type mismatch` with the very last usage of daysArr selected

The test-sub I'm using to call the function looks like this:

```
Sub HentDager()

    Dim daysArray() As Integer

    daysArray = GenererDager(2, 2017)

    Debug.Print daysArray(4)

End Sub
```

Calling this sub in the Immediate window with `HentDager()` produces the following error: `Compile error: Expected: =`

I have been pretty much stuck on this problem for a while now, and I have been rewriting the code several times to identify the issue(s), but so far I have been unable to solve it. I might have produced more errors than what I have fixed in the process, as it have dawned on me that I have no clue what I'm really doing right now :-)

Comment: You are stipulating that the function returns an integer but then expecting it to return an array.

Comment: Another point to raise is you redim daysArr with the value of actualDays. Given that option base default is 0 then you're actually dimensioning it as (0 to x) then treating it like it is a base of 1. Ideally set your min/max appropriately with Redim daysArr(1 to actualDays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare your objects and function as Variant to pass arrays.

Further more, your function needed a few changes :

- `actualDays = actualDays - 1` because you returned the 1st value for which it isn't a date!
- `ReDim daysArr(1 To actualDays)` to avoid having an empty value on the 1st index of the array,
  which would have been `daysArr(0)`

Working function (tested):

```
Function GenererDager(ByVal month As Integer, ByVal year As Integer) As Variant
    Dim dateFormat As String, daysArr() As Variant, actualDays As Integer, dayCheck As Integer, daysToArray As Integer
    actualDays = 1

    ' Find the number of actual days in given month
    For dayCheck = 1 To 31
        dateFormat = month & "/" & dayCheck & "/" & year ' mm/dd/yyyy format
        If IsDate(dateFormat) Then
            actualDays = actualDays + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next dayCheck
    actualDays = actualDays - 1
    ' Redimension the array with the actual number of days in the month
    ReDim daysArr(1 To actualDays)

    ' Populate the array with the correct number of days
    For daysToArray = 1 To actualDays
        daysArr(daysToArray) = daysToArray
    Next daysToArray

    GenererDager = daysArr
End Function
```

Tests :

```
Sub HentDager()
    Dim daysArray() As Variant
    daysArray = GenererDager(2, 2017)
    'Display last day of the month in the immediate window
    Debug.Print daysArray(UBound(daysArray))
End Sub
```

After a bit of trial and error, here is an example using `Integer` :

```
Sub TestIntSub()

    Dim TestInt() As Integer
    TestInt = FctIntArr

    Debug.Print TestInt(1) & "|" & TestInt(2)

End Sub

Public Function FctIntArr() As Integer()
    Dim IntArr() As Integer
    ReDim IntArr(1 To 2)
    IntArr(1) = 545
    IntArr(2) = 232

    FctIntArr = IntArr
End Function
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that does indeed work. Good call on subtracting from actualDays, I didn't catch that. I suppose the my major issue was that I was trying to pass the Array as an Integer instead of Variant?

Comment: @M.A. : Yup, it was! It seems tempting to define precisely the type of an array if you know what type of data will be in it, but it's (at best) of no use almost every time.

Comment: so in other words, I should generally stick to Variant whenever I need to return an array? :-)

Comment: @M.A. : Exactly! ;)

Comment: @M.A. : I added a working example using `Integer` if you want to check it out!

Comment: That will be helpful for future reference, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the return type of the function correctly -

```
Function GenererDager(ByVal month As Integer, ByVal year As Integer) As Integer
```

Change it to

```
Function GenererDager(ByVal month As Integer, ByVal year As Integer) As Variant
```

Comment: After that change it seems like the code is running (Debug.Print is triggering), but I still get a `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`

Comment: @M.A. : You have to change everything to a `Variant`, check my answer for further details/corrections

Comment: @M.A. Check R3uK's answer, it's more thorough. Your problem is with the declaring variables to types that cannot handle arrays for ex. In your case as I`nteger`

Comment: Makes sense now, I must have been confused about declaring datatypes when dealing with arrays somewhere in between reading tutorials

Answer (score 1):

few things that seems to be wrong are

1. your return value of the function is actually dimmed as an integer rather than as integer()
2. instead of dimming the daysarray as array just dim it as a variant and assign the value

Comment: `Dim TestInt as Integer()` will throw a `Syntax Error`, please check a bit before posting

Comment: actually try declaring the function return value as integer() as in function genererdager(byval month as integer,byval year as integer) as integer() i checked the code and it ran without an error. i use excel 2016. i am not sure about other versions though.

Comment: Sorry for being so blunt, the function works indeed, but you have to make a bit differently for variables. I've added an example in my answer to provide a working example!

Comment: Ah, very good point @SivaprasathV. That is something I did not consider at all. I rewrote the code to use Variant - I suppose since it's of the Variant datatype it doesn't require the parenthesis?